# are all the messages present in ros supported in ros2

Tags: ros, ros-bouncy, add-message-files

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i saw the list of messages in ros , it alot ,. But in ros2 , it is very less. I had a doubt whether all the messages support is present in ros2 . If not when are they planning to support them

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319391/are-all-the-messages-present-in-ros-supported-in-ros2-./) by [Addy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/40239/addy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-25**:
I believe an answer to this question also depends on what "messages present in ROS" actually means.

Which messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I checked and to me it looks like all the ROS1 messages are present in ROS2.

Here you can see the ROS standard messages

https://github.com/ros/common_msgs

The ROS2 standard messages on the other hand live here

https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces

Plus some additional navigation messages https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/master/nav2_msgs

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0